# How to use lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer for xgboost classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lime

I wrote a basic code for my binary classification problem.
I have problems about understanding how lime works.
Actually it has one hot encoders and scaler by using pipeline but, I tried to simplify the code as I couldn't progress. But I don't understand what is the problem?

```
categorical_features = []
counter = 0
feature_names = []
for i in df.columns:
    if i not in target_columns :
        feature_names.append(i)
    counter = counter + 1
    if df[i].dtype == 'O':
        categorical_features.append(counter)

df = df.to_numpy()
categorical_names = {}
for feature in categorical_features:
    le = sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(df[:, feature])
    df[:, feature] = le.transform(df[:, feature])
    categorical_names[feature] = le.classes_

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

model= xgb.XGBClassifier(objective="binary:logistic",
                          colsample_bytree = 0.5
                          )


#Define a pipeline
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This is the basic version of my code;

And then i want to see ;

```
import lime
import lime.lime_tabular
class_names = ['0','1']
explainer = lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(X_train ,feature_names = feature_names,class_names=class_names,
                                                   categorical_features=categorical_features, 
                                                   categorical_names=categorical_names, kernel_width=3
from lime.lime_text import LimeTextExplainer
explainer = LimeTextExplainer(class_names=class_names))
```

But i got following error;

> list index out of range (>  explainer = lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer...)

Please ask if I'm missing information and I'll complete it.

Comment: Your example is inconsistent. You start with a dataframe `df` to get some variables, but then fit the model on data from `X` and `y`. What is their relation and how to match them? Also, please provide some sample data to make a single, coherent code snippet to reproduce the error.